# Proof of the direction of directional derivative is convex

Tags: convex-analysis

Consider the directional derivative: 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directional_derivative

How to prove the following is cvx in $v$ (the direction of directional derivative):

**$h(v) = $inf $_{a \geq 0} \frac {f(x+av)-f(x)}{a}$  with $f$ is cvx and $x \in$dom $f$**.

It looks like a pointwise infimum? 
Any hint of proving this?  I have no idea where I can start.

Comment: Does cvx mean convex? Why so cryptic? I presume you mean $a\ge 0$? Show that $h$ is positive homogeneous and subadditive. I had forgotten I had answered part of this a long time ago: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function#Properties.

Comment: Excuse me, I meant the following link: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/304608/27978.